# How to make a default button in UWP app using XAML?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to declare a button as default in UWP app but receive an error:

> The property 'IsDefault' was not found in type 'Button'

How can I make a default button in UWP app?

Comment: Do you mean setting the focus?

Comment: There are button, textbox and slider on the page. I need a Button which user can invoke by pressing the ENTER key. In WPF I do it by setting 'IsDefault' property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not easy or clean way to solve your problem because IsDefault is not available for uwp apps.
if you are using MVVM or you want to reuse your code I recommend you to use Behaviors and follow the examples that the other guys posted.

Answer (score 5):

I down know what IsDefault is in WPF but to get if a button is pressed in UWP you can use [CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.aspx). Create a Method that will be called from when the button is pressed or `VirtualKey.Enter` is clicked.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += MainPage_KeyDown; ;
}

private void MainPage_KeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.VirtualKey)
    {
        case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter:
            // handler for enter key
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple `if (args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Enter) { /* handler for enter key */ }` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

You can use key down event which you can place on any textbox for example if you are making a login page then probably there will be 2 textboxes for username and password then just add key down event handler to textbox as it will be the last mandatory field like this:

```
<PasswordBox KeyDown="PasswordKeyDown"/>
```

then you can handle this event as:

```
 using System.Windows.Input;

private void PasswordKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        Login();
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to do this using only XAML and without code behind

Answer (score 0):

> I need a Button which user can invoke by pressing the ENTER key.

In an UWP app, by default a `Button` can be invoked by pressing the Enter key. So I guess what you want is setting the focus on this `Button` when there are some other `UIElement`s in your page.

You can refer to [Keyboard navigation among UI elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/accessibility/keyboard-accessibility#keyboard_navigation_among_UI_elements),

> By default, the tab order of controls is the same as the order in which they are added to a design surface, listed in XAML, or programmatically added to a container.

To focus on the `Button` which is not the first element, you can just give the `TabIndex="1"` property to your `Button`, this property can make your `Button` get focus whenever the page is loaded, but if you change the focus on other controls in this page, you will need to reselect this button by mouse clicking, touching or TAB key.